# Why is the correlation of an observable and its derivative zero?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions

Why is the correlation of an observable and it's derivative zero?

And why does this not only hold for $\langle A(t) \dot A(t) \rangle $ but also for $\langle A(0) \dot A(t) \rangle $ ? These averages are supposed to be ensamble averages.

A concrete example would be $\langle \delta \rho_{-q} \delta \dot  \rho_{-q} \rangle$ where $\delta \rho_{q}$ is the fourier transformation of $\rho(r)-\langle \rho \rangle$ the derivation of the density of a liquid from it's average density.

Comment: Can you give a reference that $\langle A(t) \dot{A}(t) \rangle$ is zero? This doesn't seem true if I just work it out for simple cases. Are you assuming a thermal state or something like that?

Comment: Hey wow you were quick with an answer this was a note in a "non equilibrium statistical mechanics" lecture in a part about mode coupling. I'll have to go to bed now but I'll try to honor your effort to help by trying to get some kind of restiction of what could be ment. The full quote is just "The correlation function of an observable and its derivative is always zero" so not very helpfull and sadly without anything to substatiate.

Comment: So I am back. This part of the text is concerned with classical thermodynamical observables $A$ that can be written as a function of vectors of phase space $\vec X$. These observables are viewed as part of a hilbert space with the equilibrium correlation as an inner product $(A,B)=\int d\vec X f_{eq} A(\vec X) B^*(\vec X,t)$ and time development through the Liouville equation.

Comment: What does the * mean in $B^*$ and why does $B$ depend on $t$ while $A$ does not? What is $f_\text{eq}$?

Comment: sorry the star is the comples conjugate and $f_{eq}$ is the equilibrium probability distribution. The time dependency of one of the variables seems to depend on the definition sometimes the inner product is defined with it sometimes without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a harmonic oscillator wherein

$$a(t) = a e^{-i \omega t} \quad \text{and} \quad a^\dagger (t) = a^\dagger e^{i \omega t} \, .$$

The derivatives are

$$\dot{a}(t) = -i \omega a(t) \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{a}^\dagger (t) = i \omega a ^\dagger (t) \, .$$

Consider the observable $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ defined by$^{[1]}$

\begin{align}
X(t) &\equiv \frac{1}{2} ( a(t) + a^\dagger (t) )\\
Y(t) &\equiv \frac{-i}{2}(a(t) - a^\dagger (t) )
\end{align}

The derivatives are

\begin{align}
\dot{X}(t) &= \frac{-i\omega}{2} (a(t) - a^\dagger (t)) = \omega Y(t) \\
\dot{Y}(t) &= \frac{-\omega}{2}(a(t) + a^\dagger(t)) = -\omega X(t) \, .
\end{align}

These equations are solved by

\begin{align}
X(t) = X \cos(\omega t) + Y \sin(\omega t) \\
Y(t) = Y \cos(\omega t) - X \sin(\omega t)
\end{align}

where $X$ and $Y$ without time dependence written means implicitly $t=0$.
Note that these are just classical equations of motion.

Now we can turn the crank:

\begin{align}
\langle X(t) \dot{X}(t) \rangle
= \omega \langle & X(t) Y(t) \rangle \\
= \omega \langle & (X\cos(\omega t) + Y \sin(\omega t)) \\
& (Y \cos(\omega t) - X \sin(\omega t)) \rangle \\
= \omega \langle & X Y \cos(\omega t)^2 - Y X\sin(\omega t)^2) \\
- & X^2 \cos(\omega t) \sin(\omega t) + Y^2 \cos(\omega t) \sin(\omega t) \rangle
\, .
\end{align}

I don't think this is generally identically zero.
If the original poster could specify that he's interested in particular cases, such as time averages or thermal states then we can go further.

$[1]$: I'm not being careful about the normalization with this definition. Don't take the presence/absence of $\sqrt{2}$ factors seriously here.

Comment: I guess this should count as a counter example. I found one example were I think this statement has been applied, atleast I don't see any other reasons stated anywhere $\langle \delta \rho_{-q} \dot \delta \rho_{-q} \rangle$ where $\delta \rho_{q}$ is the fourier transformation of $\rho(r)-\langle \rho \rangle$ the derivation of the density of a liquid from it's average density.